# Query filtering with Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have a problem that I need to filter query result with Objectify. Typically here is what the  String @Key field on stored entities would look like:

- `uid:jamesm:points`
- `uid:jsmith:points`
- `uid:jax:points`
- `uid:ken:points`

Now I want to do a query filter like this for the @Key field:

```
uid:j*:points
```

Where, I am expecting to get the first three (3) entities listed above. Is this possible with Objectify?

Comment: are you looking for a LIKE query ? http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_do_a_like_query_(LIKE_"foo%") , maybe something similar to this 1 `String start = "uid:j";
    ... = ofy.query(MyEntity.class).filter("field >=", start).filter("field <", start + "\uFFFD:points");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As described before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902019/what-is-the-best-filter-to-query-a-full-name-datastore-property-using-only-the-f/11902668#11902668), you can do this, but only if you compare start of the string: `uid:j*`

```
ofy.query(EntityClass.class).filter("property >=", "uid:j")
                            .filter("property <", "uid:j" + "\ufffd");
```

Comment: You mean this will not work: ofy.query(MyEntity.class).filter("field >=", start).filter("field <", start + "\uFFFD:points"); ?