# How to implement auto suggestion (auto complete) functionality in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to implement auto suggest functionality in Google App Engine (GAE/GWT).

The client side of the implementation works fine with GWT SuggestBox and RPC. 
My main issue is the server side of the implementation. I tried the Google search API but it seems that there is a limitation of 250MB of total indexed data and the search can be performed on complete words and not parts of each word!

How should I approach this? I read that lucene or solr is not supported in GAE. 
I would appreciate your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken this approach and it works fine for me:

1. Split up text into separate words. Get rid of duplicates, special characters and short words (in, of, and, etc..).
2. Add this list of words to entity as a list property.
3. Search via [text range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902019/what-is-the-best-filter-to-query-a-full-name-datastore-property-using-only-the-f/11902668#11902668): `listProperty >= wordPart && listProperty < wordPart + "\ufffd"`

Comment: Does this solution costs a lot on GAE?

Comment: There is a cost with storing an indexed list of properties. The cost of query is the same as any other query.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve a basic text search using these techniques described here: http://googlecode.blogspot.com.br/2010/05/google-app-engine-basic-text-search.html

In short:

Build a query using `content >= yourQuery && content < yourQuery + "\ufffd"`, where the `content` property of your entity can be a String or a List of Strings.